Conflicts loading ArcPy and arcgisbinding packages simultaneously
After working fine for the last couple of months I have encoutered a problem when loading the ArcPy and arcgisbinding packages in R simultaneously.
The inital error message was returned when I ran arcpy$CheckOutExtension("Cartography") while the arcgisbinding package was loaded by a function run earlier. This is said error:
C:\Users\LEON~1.THO\CONDA~1\envs\r-arcpy\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import,
therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been
loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service 
from . import _distributor_init

List of 22
$ python              : chr "C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/python.exe"
$ libpython           : chr "C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/python39.dll"
$ pythonhome          : chr "C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy"
$ pythonpath          : chr "C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcPy;C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy\\python39.zip;C:"| __truncated__
$ prefix              : chr "C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy"
$ exec_prefix         : chr "C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy"
$ base_exec_prefix    : chr "C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy"
$ virtualenv          : chr ""
$ virtualenv_activate : chr ""
$ executable          : chr "C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy\\python.exe"
$ base_executable     : chr "C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy\\python.exe"
$ version_string      : chr "3.9.18 [MSC v.1931 64 bit (AMD64)]"
$ version             : chr "3.9"
$ architecture        : chr "64bit"
$ anaconda            : logi FALSE
$ conda               : chr "True"
$ numpy               :List of 2
  ..$ path   : chr "C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/Lib/site-packages/numpy"
  ..$ version:Class 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
  .. ..$ : int [1:3] 1 20 1
$ required_module     : chr "arcgis"
$ required_module_path: chr "C:\\Users\\LEON~1.THO\\CONDA~1\\envs\\r-arcpy\\lib\\site-packages\\arcgis\\__init__.p"
$ available           : logi TRUE
$ python_versions     : chr "C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/python.exe"
$ forced              : chr "import(\"arcgis\")"
- attr(*, "class")= chr "py_config"
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Python module arcpy was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

Following the suggestion on (re)installing the mkl-service package from the given GitHub page yielded:
## Using --user flag workaround when installing mkl-service due to permission restrictions
python -m pip install --user mkl-service
Requirement already satisfied: mkl-service in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mkl-service) (1.15.0)

Running either of the functions that are loading Arcpy or arcgisbinding seperately works as intended. Changing the order in which the packages are loaded, results in an error from whichever package was loaded last.
When loading the ArcPy package first and then running arcgisbinding::arc.check_product() the following error is returned:
Error: Could not bind to a valid ArcGIS Pro installation.`

Running reticulate::py_config() returns:
python:         C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/python39.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy
version:        3.9.18 [MSC v.1931 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/leon.thoma/.conda/envs/r-arcpy/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.20.1
arcgis:         C:\Users\LEON~1.THO\CONDA~1\envs\r-arcpy\lib\site-packages\arcgis\__init__.p

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python() function

The above is consistent for all cases, i.e. only loading arcgisbinding, loading arcgisbinding then arcpy, only arcpy, arcpy then arcgisbinding.
I don't know how to dive deeper into what causes the issue. Any suggestions are welcome.
Additional info:
Running ArcGis Pro 3.1.
arcgisbinding version 1.0.1.306
Session info of a fresh R session.
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1    tools_4.3.1       rstudioapi_0.16.0

Default Python interpreter in R-Studio is set to use the automatically build conda environment called 'r-arcpy' using Python 3.9.18
